# Dedicated Video Ram

Tags: memory, video, bios

I searched google so I can increase my dedicated video RAM and I found that I can increase it from BIOS.
But every time I change it when I start my computer and see my dedicated video RAM from (right click=> screen resolution=> advanced settings) I find out that nothing changed.

[image]

Can you help me  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.)

```
Windows Key + R -> regeidt :
Go to 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Intel\GMM
Create the GMM key if it does not yet exist.
Create a Dword 32 Bit with the name :
DedicatedSegmentSize 
Enter 512 as decimal.
```

Reboot!